# Running Minecraft Java 1.17 with an older version of OpenGL

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I am trying to run the Minecraft Java Edition 1.17 on an Intel i3 M370 with integrated graphics, but I keep getting this error upon starting the game:

> GLFW error 65542: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL.

I tried to update my graphics drivers in the device manager on Windows, as well as using Intel's driver updater. Both of them failed to update drivers, because no updates were available.

I want to be able to play Minecraft 1.17 on my outdated hardware. Is it possible?

Comment: Try the steps on this website:
https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-minecraft-opengl-errors/